# Node.js tcp socket write trouble

Tags: node.js

I have a problem with nodejs. I have a python twisted tcp server and when I am trying to do this:

```
var socket = server.net.createConnection(server.controllerPort, 
                                         server.controllerHost);

socket.on('data', function(data) {
    log('RESPONSE: ' + data);
});

socket.on('connect', function() {

    socket.write("1 message \r\n");
    socket.write("2 message \r\n");

    socket.destroy();
});
```

instead of 2 messages, twisted receives `"1 message \r\n 2 message \r\n")`

Of course, I tested by using python, php, c++ and it works. But I am having trouble doing the same in nodejs.

Comment: Can you show a piece of your server side code? Possibly also a piece of the other clients?

Comment: twisted i took from examples(echo server) and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP does not necessarily send data line-wise.  So if you have on your server side the something like

```
class Echo(protocol.Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        ---do something with data---
```

then TCP makes no guarantees how often dataReceived will be called.  It might, in principle, be called just once with "1 message \r\n2message \r\n", twice with "1 message \r\n" and "2 message\r\n", but also split differently, e.g., twice with "1 mes" and "sage \r\n2message".

You can force node.js to "flush" the write buffer to the socket after each call to `socket.write` as follows:

```
socket.setNoDelay(true);
```

(must be called before the `socket.write`, of course).

The [wikipedia article on TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) provides more details on TCP, especially relevant is the section "Forcing data delivery".  Details on `socket.setNoDelay()` in the [node.js documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_setnodelay_nodelay).